# Sonarlint compaining about unused variables that really are used

Tags: java, static-analysis, sonarlint

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

`public void test() {
        Stream.of(aSet.entrySet(), anotherSet.entrySet())
              .flatMap(Collection::stream)
              .forEach((es) -> {
                  try {
                      //Complains on unused variable message.
                      Value value = es.getValue();
                      ...use value.
                  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                      String key = es.getKey();
                      //Complains on unused variable message.
                      String message = " (#" + key + ")";
                      throw new IllegalArgumentException(message, e);
                  }
              });
    }`

**The fact that this piece of code only uses the key variable in the catch clause is not the case because i get this error in other places as well.**

This seems like a strange thing for sonar (sonarlint) to complain about. 
Because to me it the variable is used, and should not get caught by the `Unused local variable` rule.
Am I wrong or is this a valid complaint?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Could you explain if you have resolved this ?

Comment: This codesample is not minimal and working, because I don't get a lint for the `key` variable, because you used it in the construction of the message object. And the first variable `value` is not used that is why you get the unused variable lint for it. So that is actually a valid complaint.